# Debugging SQL MERGE

Tags: sql-server, debugging, merge

I would like to debug the following code:

```
MERGE PlDayCap AS TGT
USING (SELECT MID, CalDate, SUM(CapAva) as aTime 
       FROM PSP 
       WHERE CalDate > DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()) 
       GROUP BY CalDate, MID) AS SRC(MID, cDate, aTime) ON (SRC.cDate = TGT.cDate AND SRC.MID = TGT.MID)

WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN  
       UPDATE SET TGT.aTime = SRC.aTime

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (cDate, MID, aTime, uTime) 
         VALUES (SRC.cDate, SRC.MID, SRC.aTime, 0)      

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE;
```

which runs, but doesn't return the expected results.

The target table is empty at the moment, so a `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` part should be executed, but it doesn't work and I am not even able to say, whether it is because the `INSERT` statement has not been called, or if there's an error in this statement.

I usually use following SQL debugging methods:

- validating results in database tables
- PRINT or RAISEERROR with low priority
- a special table DevelopmentLog for checking debug data, which cannot be checked in database tables, but can be read and logged at execution time using separate INSERT statement.

But nothing is available within `MERGE` conditions, where one can only have  `DELETE`, `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statements and work only with defined source and target tables, as far as I know.

I know that SQL debugging options are poor, but I am hoping to find a way through...

Comment: You can assume (to within a small margin of possibility) that `MERGE` does not have some sort of bug where it does not insert rows if it has rows to insert. Check what the inner `SELECT` returns. Check what it returns if you `LEFT JOIN` it with your target table on the target conditions. Those are your debugging aids. `MERGE` is not magic; in particular, it doesn't do anything that can't also be done with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` on their own. Just simpler (and even then only sometimes).

Comment: I forgot to mention, inner SELECT was checked ans is fine. The LEFT JOIN trick is a good hint (it probably deserves to be put in as an answer), it lead me to alias mismatch, but still it doesn't seem to be source of the problems as it is equal to inner SELECT, as expected.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - needlessly pedantic, perhaps, but it does do *one* thing that you can't achieve using `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` - it allows for a single action that performs a mixture of those three commands and only revalidates constraints after all of them are evaluated. E.g. you can have mutually cross-referencing foreign keys that requires an insert *and* an update in order that they're always valid.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'd say that's a worthwhile addendum, not "needlessly pedantic". Having said that, a database design that requires the use of `MERGE` to satisfy the constraints may be worth reconsidering as more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this query, are you sure SRC table has valid records that will allow merge.

You can use [OUTPUT clause with MERGE](http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/06/using-the-output-clause-with-t-sql-merge/) to check the results as soon as they are run.

> [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) Returns information from, or expressions based on, each row affected by an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. These results can be returned to the processing application for use in such things as confirmation messages, archiving, and other such application requirements.

```
MERGE PlDayCap AS TGT
USING
    (SELECT MID, CalDate, SUM(CapAva) as aTime FROM PSP WHERE CalDate > DATEADD(DAY,-5,GETDATE()) GROUP BY CalDate,MID) 
    AS SRC(MID, cDate, aTime) 
ON (SRC.cDate = TGT.cDate AND SRC.MID = TGT.MID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET TGT.aTime = SRC.aTime
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (cDate, MID, aTime, uTime) VALUES (SRC.cDate, SRC.MID, SRC.aTime, 0)        
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

Comment: This is a great hint, I didn't think of an OUTPUT. I will mark it as an answer. The inner SELECT gives valid result table. However, a mystery goes on, because I get a list of only UPDATE statements with lines corresponding to the inner SELECT. I wonder, how's that possible with target table **empty**.